# Windows TCP/IP Listener Service "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted"

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, tcplistener

I have a Windows Service which listens for tcp/ip connections.  When I run the service I get the error "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted".  I can run the code in a console application without issues.

Service begins and creates listener on its own thread:

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(IpAddress.Any), 8100);
        this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
        this.listenThread.Start();
    }
```

Start the listener:

```
private void ListenForClients()
    {
        this.tcpListener.Start(); //<-----Produces the error
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        this.tcpListener.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure your development environment is not already listening on that port? Maybe a frozen console application? Do you stop the thread and close the port(s)?

Comment: That's exactly what it was, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tested your code and it works on my computer.
If you want to know which program is using that port on your computer I suggest you use the "tcpview" tool from the SysInteralSuite made by microsoft.

You can find it here.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx

Comment: I checked netstat and didn't see the port in use.  That will teach me a lesson, thanks.